# ERROR: Could not build wheels for tulipy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, cmd, pip, build-tools, pep517

so I have checked every post that relates to this issue and I still can't seem to make this work. I am trying to install tulipy using pip on a Windows machine. I've installed numerous other pip based programs with no issues. I tried reinstalling VS Build Tools, but that doesn't seem to help either. I need tulipy for a project I'm working on, so I can't use any alternatives.

```
C:\Users\bette>pip install tulipy --user
Collecting tulipy
  Using cached tulipy-0.4.0.tar.gz (110 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\bette\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from tulipy) (1.19.5)
Building wheels for collected packages: tulipy
  Building wheel for tulipy (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\python39\python.exe' 'C:\Users\bette\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\bette\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpuwzd3c74'
       cwd: C:\Users\bette\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gkcz217u\tulipy_8179e3516bd64c689a0168ed407c13fc
  Complete output (27 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tulipy
  copying tulipy\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tulipy
  running build_ext
  skipping 'tulipy/lib\__init__.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  building 'tulipy.lib' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\libindicators
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\tulipy
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\tulipy\lib
  D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ilibindicators -Itulipy/lib -IC:\Users\bette\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nl5462ni\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\python39\include -Ic:\python39\include -ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE -ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt -ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared -ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um -ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt /Tclibindicators/tiamalgamation.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\libindicators/tiamalgamation.obj
  tiamalgamation.c
  D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ilibindicators -Itulipy/lib -IC:\Users\bette\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nl5462ni\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\python39\include -Ic:\python39\include -ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE -ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt -ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared -ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um -ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt /Tctulipy/lib\__init__.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\tulipy/lib\__init__.obj
  __init__.c
  c:\users\bette\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-env-nl5462ni\overlay\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
  tulipy/lib\__init__.c(8102): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
  c:\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
  tulipy/lib\__init__.c(10033): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
  c:\python39\include\cpython/unicodeobject.h(446): note: see declaration of '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length'
  tulipy/lib\__init__.c(10049): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
  c:\python39\include\cpython/unicodeobject.h(446): note: see declaration of '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length'
  error: command 'D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for tulipy
Failed to build tulipy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for tulipy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be old, but if anyone is looking how to install tulipy.
It's in https://pypi.org/project/newtulipy/.

```
pip install newtulipy
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pip install pip==18.1
```

if that doesn't work try this:

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

If that doesn't work try updating Microsoft visual studio to a current version
if that doesn't work...

Comment: Now I get this:
`code`C:\Users\bette>pip install tulipy --user
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.cli.main'

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I was using Python 3.9 and that was incompatible with `tulipy`. When I installed Python 3.7.6 it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The latest supported version is up to python3.7, if your python version is higher, it is not supported.

You can download whl file of tulipy form [here](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/27/ba/fe5e9c1de77c3bc6892d67f3f2ef3246604f66918a37c8f9ac416b662f5c/tulipy-0.4.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl).

Then use `pip install tulipy-0.4.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` to install.